# Find if a word is plural of another

Tags: go, pluralize

I am writing a program in Go to generate a report of crimes in my University. I have run into a roadblock where I need to find if one word is a plural of another. I am making a map of crimes first

```
crimes := make(map[string]int)
```

then, adding crimes to the map with the number of occurrences as int

```
for i := 0; i < len(feed.Items); i++ {
  crimes[feed.Items[i].Title[11:]]++
}
```

Now, the problem arises when there are entries like, "Armed Robberies (with a count of 1)" and "Armed Robbery (with a count of 2)". I want to check if a word is a plural of another. In this case, I want to make a single entry for "Armed Robbery (with a count of 3)". I could not find a package for doing this. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **inflections**. Basically, it is the black art of determining the various forms of a word, in particular singular from plural, or the opposite.

There are libraries for this, mostly inspired from the Ruby On Rails `ActiveSupport::Inflector` system, see for example https://github.com/jinzhu/inflection.

Also see http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~damian/papers/HTML/Plurals.html for a very interesting read about algorithms for english pluralization.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the links. The second link sets me on the right track.